# Como ler um arquivo de certificado digital com php

Tags: php, certificado-digital

Tenho um sistema em que ele faz o armazenamento de certificado digital, preciso de algumas informações alem do arquivo em si, uma dessas informações é a data de vencimento do certificado.

A questão é, como ler este arquivo de forma que eu possa pegar a data de vencimento deste certificado?

O certificado é do tipo A1, e a extensão do arquivo está em pfx.

Achei uma solução [neste post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nfephp/0AWYCgvqQ8E).

Answer (score 6):

Segue um exemplo da leitura do certificado em formato 'pfx', espero que ajude!

```
<?php
//Caminho do Certificado
$pfxCertPrivado = 'certificado.pfx';
$cert_password  = 'senha';

if (!file_exists($pfxCertPrivado)) {
   echo "Certificado não encontrado!! " . $pfxCertPrivado;
}

$pfxContent = file_get_contents($pfxCertPrivado);

if (!openssl_pkcs12_read($pfxContent, $x509certdata, $cert_password)) {
   echo "O certificado não pode ser lido!!";
} else {

   $CertPriv   = array();
   $CertPriv   = openssl_x509_parse(openssl_x509_read($x509certdata['cert']));

   $PrivateKey = $x509certdata['pkey'];

   $pub_key = openssl_pkey_get_public($x509certdata['cert']);
   $keyData = openssl_pkey_get_details($pub_key);

   $PublicKey  = $keyData['key'];

   echo '<br>'.'<br>'.'--- Dados do Certificado ---'.'<br>'.'<br>';
   echo $CertPriv['name'].'<br>';                           //Nome
   echo $CertPriv['hash'].'<br>';                           //hash
   echo $CertPriv['subject']['C'].'<br>';                   //País
   echo $CertPriv['subject']['ST'].'<br>';                  //Estado
   echo $CertPriv['subject']['L'].'<br>';                   //Município
   echo $CertPriv['subject']['CN'].'<br>';                  //Razão Social e CNPJ / CPF
   echo date('d/m/Y', $CertPriv['validTo_time_t'] ).'<br>'; //Validade
   echo $CertPriv['extensions']['subjectAltName'].'<br>';   //Emails Cadastrados separado por ,
   echo $CertPriv['extensions']['authorityKeyIdentifier'].'<br>'; 
   echo $CertPriv['issuer']['OU'].'<br>';                   //Emissor 
   echo '<br>'.'<br>'.'--- Chave Pública ---'.'<br>'.'<br>';
   print_r($PublicKey);
   echo '<br>'.'<br>'.'--- Chave Privada ---'.'<br>'.'<br>';
   echo $PrivateKey;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar a função [openssl_x509_parse()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-x509-parse.php) para ler o certificado e então retornar as informações em forma de `array`. Por exemplo:

```
$certpath = "certificado.cer";
$certinfo = openssl_x509_parse(file_get_contents($certpath));
echo "Data de validade: " . $certinfo['validFrom_time_t'];
```

Comment: Amigo, um detalhe que esqueci de adicionar a minha pergunta, é que a extensão do arquivo está em 'pfx', sendo assim, tem alguma maneira de eu converter este arquivo antes de fazer a leitura?

Comment: Achei uma solução que inclui uma parte do que você colocou na sua resposta.

Comment: @Mathdesigner47, a solução que encontrou precisa transformar `.pfx` em `.cer` ? Se não, e achou uma forma mais fácil, por favor poste, que vou aprimorar meu código. Atualmente minha função executa em `shell` a conversão do arquivo em `.pub` para conseguir ler os dados.